# How to test my code which internally calls AWS services

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, testing, amazon-cognito

I am looking for possible ways to mock or stub AWS services.

Is there any ready to use third party commercial or open source framework which we can use to mock AWS services (eg. Cognito, IAM, Lambda & S3) ?

Comment: You mean API mock? What language?

Comment: Yes. looking for java. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Few of the options I am aware of are,

1. [Localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) (This supports most of the AWS services)
2. [Minio](https://www.minio.io/) - This one supports S3 and Lambda
3. [s3rver](https://github.com/jamhall/s3rver) - Supports only AWS S3
4. [moto](https://github.com/spulec/moto) - Potential candidate if you use boto3 lib